# Изменение вида страницы при условии авторизации

Tags: javascript, php, html

Как Можно изменить кнопку на странице, если пользователь авторизован? Т.е если пользователь авторизован, то должна отображаться кнопка log out, и кнопка login, если он не авторизован. Условие авторизации проверить могу, но вот как изменить кнопку на странице не знаю

Answer (score 0):

При авторизации обычно сохраняют в сессию информацию о том что пользователь авторизировался, не забудьте вызвать функцию session_start();
тогда можно сделать так

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])
  выводим одну кнопку
else выводим другую кнопку.
```